# How to add JSON data in select and option tag?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dynamic-arrays

I have this html code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CarInfoStyle.css">
</head>
<script src="CarInfoJavascript.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="searchfilter">
        <div class="searchwrapper">
            <select class="selectClass" id="minYear">
                <option value="minYear">Select Year</option>
                <option value="(All)">ALL</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
            </select>
            to
            <select class="selectClass" id="maxYear">
                <option value="maxYear">Select Year</option>
                <option value="(All)">ALL</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
            </select>


            <select id="make" onchange="DropdownOption()">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Make</option>
                <option value="alfa romeo">ALFA ROMEO</option>
                <option value="audi">AUDI</option>
                <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
                <option value="daihatsu">DAIHATSU</option>
                <option value="ford">FORD</option>
                <option value="honda">HONDA</option>
                <option value="lexus">LEXUS</option>
                <option value="mazda">MAZDA</option>
                <option value="mercedes-benz">MERCEDES-BENZ</option>
                <option value="mini">MINI</option>
                <option value="mitsubishi">MITSUBISHI</option>
                <option value="nissan">NISSAN</option>
                <option value="subaru">SUBARU</option>
                <option value="suzuki">SUZUKI</option>
                <option value="toyota" name="toyota">TOYOTA</option>
                <option value="volkswagen">VOLKSWAGEN</option>
            </select>

            <select id="Model" disabled>
                <option value="Model" name="model" selected disabled>Model</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" size="20" name="searchbox">
            <input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="Search" onclick="createTable()">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
        <table id="MyTable" cellspacing='0'>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and this JSON object code:

```
var carData = [{
    "ConditionNotes": {},
    "Photos": {},
    "RealChassisNo": "BJ5W-315859",
    "Age": 0,
    "Miles": 0,
    "ImprovementCost": 0,
    "AirBagType": 0,
    "M3": 0,
    "Category": 0,
    "IsMiles": false,
    "IsInnerCargo": false,
    "IsPreSold": false,
    "IsNoNZ": false,
    "InnerCargoNote": null,
    "DateStock": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "IsSold": false,
    "PriceSales": 0,
    "PriceConfirmation": 0,
    "PriceExport": 0,
    "PriceATSales": 0,
    "ScaledMargin": 0,
    "PriceDynamic": 0,
    "FobFees": 332000.0000,
    "OFSFees": 1440.0000,
    "CIFFees": 0,
    "FreightRate": 0,
    "PriceBase": 0,
    "MarketTerm": null,
    "IsIncludeOPC": false,
    "CustomerTerm": null,
    "LandedCost": 0,
    "NZNote": null,
    "NZStructuralNote": null,
    "NZStructuralCost": 0,
    "IDIBCInfo": null,
    "TransportStatus": null,
    "DateDeparture": "\/Date(1281801600000)\/",
    "DateArrive": "\/Date(1283788800000)\/",
    "ShipName": "Saracen Star(KB)",
    "TypeOfSale": "",
    "BuyTripCustomer": "",
    "IsSplitCurrency": false,
    "Currency": "JPY",
    "CountryID": 75,
    "IsFollowing": false,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceTerm": null,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceFees": 0,
    "PriceBaseForATNZ": 0,
    "IDVehicle": "232960",
    "Price": 0,
    "MaskChassisNo": null,
    "Make": "MAZDA",
    "Model": "FAMILIA",
    "Year": 2002,
    "Month": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Location": null,
    "Grade": "S-F",
    "Transmission": null,
    "KMS": 0,
    "EngineDisplacement": null,
    "Fuel": null,
    "Doors": null,
    "ConditionGrade": null,
    "Color": null,
    "IsPowerSteering": false,
    "IsPowerWindow": false,
    "IsAirConditioned": false,
    "InteriorColor": null,
    "InteriorType": null,
    "HasSunRoof": false,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 0,
    "WheelStyle": 0,
    "HasSpareKey": false,
    "SalesNote": null,
    "IsSale": false,
    "IsNewArrival": false,
    "IsReserved": false,
    "IsThailandStocks": false,
    "IsLeftHandDrive": false,
    "DateInspected": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "ExteriorVideo": null,
    "InteriorVideo": null,
    "IsSingaporeStocks": false,
    "IsUKStocks": false,
    "IsOriginalLHD": false,
    "CustomerPort": null,
    "Airbag": 0,
    "IsNonSmoker": false,
    "Tonnage": 0,
    "InteriorGrade": null,
    "DateConfirm": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
}, {
    "ConditionNotes": {},
    "Photos": {},
    "RealChassisNo": "ZZE127-0006450",
    "Age": 0,
    "Miles": 0,
    "ImprovementCost": 0,
    "AirBagType": 0,
    "M3": 0,
    "Category": 0,
    "IsMiles": false,
    "IsInnerCargo": false,
    "IsPreSold": false,
    "IsNoNZ": false,
    "InnerCargoNote": null,
    "DateStock": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "IsSold": false,
    "PriceSales": 0,
    "PriceConfirmation": 0,
    "PriceExport": 0,
    "PriceATSales": 0,
    "ScaledMargin": 0,
    "PriceDynamic": 0,
    "FobFees": 347000.0000,
    "OFSFees": 1440.0000,
    "CIFFees": 0,
    "FreightRate": 0,
    "PriceBase": 0,
    "MarketTerm": null,
    "IsIncludeOPC": false,
    "CustomerTerm": null,
    "LandedCost": 0,
    "NZNote": null,
    "NZStructuralNote": null,
    "NZStructuralCost": 0,
    "IDIBCInfo": null,
    "TransportStatus": null,
    "DateDeparture": "\/Date(1284480000000)\/",
    "DateArrive": "\/Date(1286208000000)\/",
    "ShipName": "Spring Sky(KB)",
    "TypeOfSale": "",
    "BuyTripCustomer": "",
    "IsSplitCurrency": false,
    "Currency": "JPY",
    "CountryID": 75,
    "IsFollowing": false,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceTerm": null,
    "FrieghtAndInsuranceFees": 0,
    "PriceBaseForATNZ": 0,
    "IDVehicle": "233407",
    "Price": 0,
    "MaskChassisNo": null,
    "Make": "TOYOTA",
    "Model": "WILL",
    "Year": 2002,
    "Month": 0,
    "Type": null,
    "Location": null,
    "Grade": "Vs",
    "Transmission": null,
    "KMS": 0,
    "EngineDisplacement": null,
    "Fuel": null,
    "Doors": null,
    "ConditionGrade": null,
    "Color": null,
    "IsPowerSteering": false,
    "IsPowerWindow": false,
    "IsAirConditioned": false,
    "InteriorColor": null,
    "InteriorType": null,
    "HasSunRoof": false,
    "Length": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "Height": 0,
    "WheelStyle": 0,
    "HasSpareKey": false,
    "SalesNote": null,
    "IsSale": false,
    "IsNewArrival": false,
    "IsReserved": false,
    "IsThailandStocks": false,
    "IsLeftHandDrive": false,
    "DateInspected": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "ExteriorVideo": null,
    "InteriorVideo": null,
    "IsSingaporeStocks": false,
    "IsUKStocks": false,
    "IsOriginalLHD": false,
    "CustomerPort": null,
    "Airbag": 0,
    "IsNonSmoker": false,
    "Tonnage": 0,
    "InteriorGrade": null,
    "DateConfirm": "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"
}];
```

and finally my JS Code:

```
function createTable() {

  var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");

  table.innerHTML = "";
  var header = table.createTHead();
  var row = header.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell1.innerHTML = "Chassis";
  cell2.innerHTML = "Year";
  cell3.innerHTML = "Make";
  cell4.innerHTML = "Model";
  cell5.innerHTML = "Model Grade";
  cell6.innerHTML = "Ship Name";

  var makevalue = document.getElementById("make").value;
  var modelvalue = document.getElementById("Model").value;
  var minYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("minYear").value);
  var maxYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxYear").value);

  for (var i = 0; i < 757; i++) {
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var chassisCell = row.insertCell(0);
    var yearCell = row.insertCell(1);
    var makeCell = row.insertCell(2);
    var modelCell = row.insertCell(3);
    var modelGradeCell = row.insertCell(4);
    var shipNameCell = row.insertCell(5);

    chassisCell.innerHTML = carData[i].RealChassisNo;
    yearCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Year;
    makeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Make;
    modelCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Model;
    modelGradeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Grade;
    shipNameCell.innerHTML = carData[i].ShipName;
  }
}


function DropdownOption(carData) {
  document.getElementById("Model").disabled = false;
  var model = document.getElementById("Model");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  var make = document.getElementById("make").value;
  model.innerHTML = "";

  option.text = "Model";
  model.add(option);
  option.innerHTML = "Model";

  if (make == "alfa romeo") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var choice = document.createElement('option');
    choice.innerHTML = "156";
    model.appendChild(choice);
  } else if (make == "audi") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var audi = ["A4", "A3", "TT"];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var choices1 = document.createElement('option');
      choices1.value = audi[i];
      choices1.innerHTML = audi[i];
      model.appendChild(choices1);
    }
  } else if (make == "bmw") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var bmw = ["116I", "118I", "120i", "120I", "1 SERIES", "320I", "323I", "MINI", "MINICOOPER", "MINI COOPER S", "X1", "X3"];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var choices2 = document.createElement('option');
      choices2.value = bmw[i];
      choices2.innerHTML = bmw[i];
      model.appendChild(choices2);
    }
  } else if (make == "daihatsu") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var choice3 = document.createElement('option');
    choice3.innerHTML = "BeGo";
    model.appendChild(choice3);
  } else if (make == "ford") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var ford = ["Escape", "Focus", "Kuga"];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var choices4 = document.createElement('option');
      choices4.value = ford[i];
      choices4.innerHTML = ford[i];
      model.appendChild(choices4);
    }
  } else if (make == "honda") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var honda = ["ACCORD", "AIR WAVE", "CIVIC", "CIVICFERIO", "CR-V", "EDIX", "ELYSION", "FIT", "HR-V", "INSPIRE", "ODYSSEY", "STEPWAGON", "STREAM"];

    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      var choices5 = document.createElement('option');
      choices5.value = honda[i];
      choices5.innerHTML = honda[i];
      model.appendChild(choices5);
    }
  } else if (make == "lexus") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var lexus = ["IS250", "IS350"];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var choices6 = document.createElement('option');
      choices6.value = lexus[i];
      choices6.innerHTML = lexus[i];
      model.appendChild(choices6);
    }
  } else if (make == "mazda") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var mazda = ["AXELA", "ATENZA", "BONGO", "DEMIGO", "FAMILIA", "MPV", "PREMACY", "VERISA"];

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      var choices7 = document.createElement('option');
      choices7.value = mazda[i];
      choices7.innerHTML = mazda[i];
      model.appendChild(choices7);
    }
  } else if (make == "mercedes-benz") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var mercedesbenz = ["A170", "A200", "C230", "C200 KOMPRESSOR"];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var choices8 = document.createElement('option');
      choices8.value = mercedesbenz[i];
      choices8.innerHTML = mercedesbenz[i];
      model.appendChild(choices8);
    }
  } else if (make == "mini") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var mini = ["COOPER", "MINI ONE"];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var choices9 = document.createElement('option');
      choices9.value = mini[i];
      choices9.innerHTML = mini[i];
      model.appendChild(choices9);
    }
  } else if (make == "mitsubishi") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var mitsubishi = ["COLT", "COLT PlUS", "DELICA", "GALANT", "GRANDIS", "LANCER", "OUTLANDER", "PAJERO", "PAJERO MINI"];

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      var choices10 = document.createElement('option');
      choices10.value = mitsubishi[i];
      choices10.innerHTML = mitsubishi[i];
      model.appendChild(choices10);
    }
  } else if (make == "nissan") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var nissan = ["BLUEBIRD SYLPHY", "CARAVAN", "CUBE", "DUALIS", "FAIRLADY", "FUGA", "JUKE", "LAFESTA", "MARCH", "MURANO", "NOTE", "NV200", "NV350 CARAVAN", "PRESAGE", "STAGEA", "SKYLINE", "TEANA", "TIIDA", "TIIDA LATIO", "VANETTE", "WINGROAD", "X-TRAIL"];

    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
      var choices11 = document.createElement('option');
      choices11.value = nissan[i];
      choices11.innerHTML = nissan[i];
      model.appendChild(choices11);
    }
  } else if (make == "subaru") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var subaru = ["EXIGA", "FORESTER", "IMPREZA", "LEGACY", "LEGACY TOURING WAGON", "TRAVIQ", "OUTBACK"];

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      var choices12 = document.createElement('option');
      choices12.value = subaru[i];
      choices12.innerHTML = subaru[i];
      model.appendChild(choices12);
    }
  } else if (make == "suzuki") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var suzuki = ["ESCUDO", "FORESTER", "JIMNY", "SWIFT", "SX-4"];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var choices13 = document.createElement('option');
      choices13.value = suzuki[i];
      choices13.innerHTML = suzuki[i];
      model.appendChild(choices13);
    }
  } else if (make == "toyota") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var toyota = ["ALLEX", "ALLION", "ALTEZZA", "AURIS", "AVENSIS", "BB", "BLADE", "CALDINA", "CAMRY", "COROLLA AXIO", "COROLLA FIELDER", "COROLLA RUNX", "ESTIMA", "HIACE", "HILUX SURF", "IPSUM", "IST", "ISIS", "IQ", "LANDCRUISER PRADO", "MARK X", "MARK ZIO", "RACTIS", "RAV4", "REGIUS ACE", "RUSH", "SUCCEED", "TOWNACE", "VANGUARD", "VITZ", "WILL", "WISH"];

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      var choices14 = document.createElement('option');
      choices14.value = toyota[i];
      choices14.innerHTML = toyota[i];
      model.appendChild(choices14);
    }
  } else if (make == "volkswagen") {
    document.getElementById("Model").options[0].disabled = true;
    var volkswagen = ["GOLF", "GOLF VARIANT", "PASSAT VARIANT", "TIGUAN", "TOUAREG"];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var choices15 = document.createElement('option');
      choices15.value = volkswagen[i];
      choices15.innerHTML = volkswagen[i];
      model.appendChild(choices15);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is what condition should I make if I want to select from the Make then select options from Model, the data will get the value of the selected Make and Model. I have tried this far not of it seems to work it will only display the cells[1-6] that I created. please help.

```
function createTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    var header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Chassis";
    cell2.innerHTML = "Year";
    cell3.innerHTML = "Make";
    cell4.innerHTML = "Model";
    cell5.innerHTML = "Model Grade";
    cell6.innerHTML = "Ship Name";

    var makevalue = document.getElementById("make").value;
    var modelvalue = document.getElementById("Model").value;
    var minYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("minYear").value);
    var maxYearvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxYear").value);

    for (var i = 0; i < 757; i++) {
      //I tried this condition not working. 
      if (carData[i].Make == makevalue && carData[i].Model == modelvalue && (carData[i].Year >= minYearvalue && carData[i].Year <= maxYearvalue)) {
        var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var chassisCell = row.insertCell(o);
        var yearCell = row.insertCell(1);
        var makeCell = row.insertCell(2);
        var modelCell = row.insertCell(3);
        var modelGradeCell = row.insertCell(4);
        var shipNameCell = row.insertCell(5);

        chassisCell.innerHTML = carData[i].RealChassisNo;
        yearCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Year;
        makeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Make;
        modelCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Model;
        modelGradeCell.innerHTML = carData[i].Grade;
        shipNameCell.innerHTML = carData[i].ShipName;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can we get a jsfiddle please?

Comment: sorry sir, slow internet in this area.

Comment: What is the issue, and what you actually want to achieve. The code seems to be OK as of now.

Comment: if (carData[i].Make == makevalue && carData[i].Model == modelvalue && (carData[i].Year >= minYearvalue && carData[i].Year <= maxYearvalue)) { this condition sir is not working. I want to sort the data by Its Make and Model when I click the option tags. example when I click: Make = TOYOTA and Model = "ALLEX" it will filter the search code. Instead of showing all the Data it will only show the make and model data for Toyota only. I filter my JSON code into 2 data only cause all the data's in it are too large too post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your array holds the lowercase of the make. Try this and you should be good to go:

```
if (carData[i]['Make'].toLowerCase() == makevalue.toLowerCase() && carData[i].Model == modelvalue && (carData[i].Year >= minYearvalue && carData[i].Year <= maxYearvalue)) {
```

you have a typo in your code:

```
var chassisCell = row.insertCell(o);
```

should be

```
var chassisCell = row.insertCell(0);
```

see a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/klickagent/dyrLw3jf/2/