# Is this the correct way for parsing JSON into var?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this carData JSON:
is this the correct for parsing JSON data?

```
var carData = '[{"ConditionNotes":{},"Photos":{},"RealChassisNo":"BJ5W-315859","Age":0,"Miles":0,"ImprovementCost":0,"AirBagType":0,"M3":0,"Category":0,"IsMiles":false,"IsInnerCargo":false,"IsPreSold":false,"IsNoNZ":false,"InnerCargoNote":null,"DateStock":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","IsSold":false,"PriceSales":0,"PriceConfirmation":0,"PriceExport":0,"PriceATSales":0,"ScaledMargin":0,"PriceDynamic":0,"FobFees":332000.0000,"OFSFees":1440.0000,"CIFFees":0,"FreightRate":0,"PriceBase":0,"MarketTerm":null,"IsIncludeOPC":false,"CustomerTerm":null,"LandedCost":0,"NZNote":null,"NZStructuralNote":null,"NZStructuralCost":0,"IDIBCInfo":null,"TransportStatus":null,"DateDeparture":"\/Date(1281801600000)\/","DateArrive":"\/Date(1283788800000)\/","ShipName":"Saracen Star(KB)","TypeOfSale":"","BuyTripCustomer":"","IsSplitCurrency":false,"Currency":"JPY","CountryID":75,"IsFollowing":false,"FrieghtAndInsuranceTerm":null,"FrieghtAndInsuranceFees":0,"PriceBaseForATNZ":0,"IDVehicle":"232960","Price":0,"MaskChassisNo":null,"Make":"MAZDA","Model":"FAMILIA","Year":2002,"Month":0,"Type":null,"Location":null,"Grade":"S-F","Transmission":null,"KMS":0,"EngineDisplacement":null,"Fuel":null,"Doors":null,"ConditionGrade":null,"Color":null,"IsPowerSteering":false,"IsPowerWindow":false,"IsAirConditioned":false,"InteriorColor":null,"InteriorType":null,"HasSunRoof":false,"Length":0,"Width":0,"Height":0,"WheelStyle":0,"HasSpareKey":false,"SalesNote":null,"IsSale":false,"IsNewArrival":false,"IsReserved":false,"IsThailandStocks":false,"IsLeftHandDrive":false,"DateInspected":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ExteriorVideo":null,"InteriorVideo":null,"IsSingaporeStocks":false,"IsUKStocks":false,"IsOriginalLHD":false,"CustomerPort":null,"Airbag":0,"IsNonSmoker":false,"Tonnage":0,"InteriorGrade":null,"DateConfirm":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(carData);
```

Comment: Which language/platform?

Comment: This is correct json parsing using javascript. I have posted on more example in support with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes you have written correct json parsing statement* in javascript.
For more, i am posting one more example of javascript json parsing.

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

Comment: thank you sir,, um, can you help me with this page sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296067/how-to-add-json-data-in-select-and-option-tag

Comment: welcome laurence, i will surely help you if it is in my experience. :)

Comment: Sir, do you have a moment? .. can you go to that link that I give to you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct way. `JSON.parse()` converts your `JSON` string into a JavaScript object.

More Details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct way, 
but if you use older browsers (that dont' support JSON.parse function) you should use eval()

```
eval ("(" + carData + ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a JSON array with only 1 element. if you have a single element why not remove the '[' at the start and ']' at the end. 
anyways, `JSON.parse(carData)` will parse your JSON successfully.
`obj[0]` would be having the details of this JSON